# Real time sphinx search min-max values for attributes

Tags: php, real-time, sphinx

We have an attribute in our real-time sphinx table called 'price', and want to allow the users to define a minimum and maximum for this when conducting their search. As it seems though, there is no way to define just one of these parameters, at least not that I can find.

The code then gets somewhat of an ugly solution by setting a ridiculous maxvalue when none is set. The classvalues in this example are just the collected $_GET variables.

So the question is, how can I make the filter just define one of the min,max values instead of both?

```
if($this->_priceRangeMin > 0 || $this->_priceRangeMax > 0)
    {
        if(($this->_priceRangeMin > 0) === false )
            $this->_priceRangeMin = 0;
        if(($this->_priceRangeMax > 0) === false )
            $this->_priceRangeMax = 4294967295;
    }
$s->SetFilterRange('price', $this->_priceRangeMin, $this->_priceRangeMax);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats wrong with the code you got? It works doesnt it?

If you really wanted to just use a inequality filter, rather than a range, could use SphinxQL to do the query. But doubt it will save you anything.

Comment: I´ve seen your name on most Sphinx-forums and you seem like an authority on the subject, so I´m gonna go with your suggestion and keep this setting. Thanks for your input :)